# How do I convert the letter entered to lowercase in python? My code does not seem to work

Tags: python, string, file, letter

I have created a hangman type game and it all works apart from if the user enters a capital letter it does not register it. The game should be case insensitive. This is the code I have tried for that part of the game.

```
def game():
  total = len(''.join(set(myword)))
  wrong_guess = 0
  correct_letters = 0
  while wrong_guess <= 7:
    print_output()
    letter = input("Guess:")
    if len(letter) >= 1:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter.lower() in myword:
                correct_letters += 1
            for i,x in enumerate(myword):
                    if x is letter.lower():
                        output[i] = letter
             
            else:
                wrong_guess += 1
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please enter a guess")
    else:
        print("Invalid input, please enter a guess")
```

Answer (score 1):

python has a built in function called string.lower()

do this

```
letter = input("Guess: ").lower()
```

Comment: says this when I tried that: TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

Comment: try letter = str(input("Guess: ")).lower()

Comment: @user1847 The line of code in this answer will not trigger that error. Note the `()` at the end of the line -- you probably forgot them.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not the proper way to compare strings or characters:

```
if x is letter.lower():
```

The `is` operator compares whether two instances are the same or not, it does not compare equality. You want to use the equality operator, `==`:

```
if x == letter.lower():
```